# Alterar repositório remoto git

Tags: git, versionamento

Estou usando uma ferramenta online para fazer o controle de versão do meu repositório `git`, gostaria de alterar o remoto para usar outra referência.

Como alterar o repositório remoto (*origin*) do git?

Comment: Ou ainda pode talvez criar dois repositórios na sua maquina ligadas a dois repositórios remoto diferentes. Em uma pasta qualquer você cria seu novo repositório e a segunda o que já existe sendo que o origin que é colocado pode ser escolhendo outra palavra se for para ajudar a identificar. No meu caso tenho dois repositório um com origin e outro com gringa. Ai quando for fazer o commit lembre de estar pelo terminal na pasta certa do repositório.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Existem algumas respostas diferentes para essa pergunta, mas a que melhor se adequou à situação foi o seguinte:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin novo_repositório_a_ser_apontado.git
```

---

Fonte: [Stack Overflow (Inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904339/github-fatal-remote-origin-already-exists)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode remover

`git remote remove origin`

adicionar um novo com o novo endereço

`git remote add origin git://suaUrl`

Alterar o diretório remoto

`git remote set-url origin git://suaUrl`

Ou pode renomeá-lo o atual e adicionar um novo.

`git remote rename origin old-origin`

`git remote add origin novaurl`

Answer (score -2):

Você pode remover o diretório remoto com:

```
git remote rm origin
```

e depois pode adicionar um novo com:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:user-name/projeto.git
```

depois faz o push pro `origin main`:

```
git push origin main
```